# How can multithreading of three or more mobile cameras be done using Python Opencv?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, camera

I'm trying to connect four mobile cams using Iriun cam application but it doesn't show all the four cams' output **in a single screen**. Is there a way/application to get the output from four cams in a single screen and analyze them? I'm going to scan four sets of QR Codes in each cam and use the output from it for a different purpose.
I want to use multi threading of cameras because the QR Codes are placed far away from each other such that the QR Codes are not covered in a single frame of the camera.

This is the basic code for my project.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

A = ['A9', 'I2', 'I19', 'I20', 'J1', 'J2', 'J20']
B1 = set(A)

while True:
    myData=[]
    success, img = cap.read()
    for barcode in decode(img):
        myData.append(barcode.data.decode('utf-8'))

    if len(myData) == A:
     while True:
        print(myData)
        print("Authorised")
        break
    else:
        print("Not authorised")
    for barcode in decode(img):
        pts = np.array([barcode.polygon],np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
        cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(255,0,255),5)
        pts2 = barcode.rect
        #cv2.putText(img,myData,(pts2[0],pts2[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.9,(255,0,255),2)
    cv2.imshow('Result',img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: You mention Iriun but provide no link to it and it doesn't seem to appear in your code? You say you have 4 cameras (but don't say what cameras nor how they are connected nor to what) and you say you want to scan 4 QR codes in each - so you have 16 QR codes, correct?

Comment: @nathancy The above code does what you asked for.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm sorry bout' giving such minimum information about it. I'll edit the code in some time